# Default value for DateTime in DevForce 2012

Tags: c#, datetime, default, devforce

I have an Entity with a System.DateTime CreatedDate member that is getting a default value of Today (no time component).  Also, the Date value for Today is cached and is the date the application was started.  Normally not a problem if you restart your process but when used in a long running Windows Service this Date value gets stale.

example:

**From my EDMX**

```
/// <summary>Gets or sets the CreatedDate. </summary>
[DataMember]
[Bindable(true, BindingDirection.TwoWay)]
[Editable(true)]
[Display(Name="CreatedDate", AutoGenerateField=true)]
[IbVal.RequiredValueVerifier( ErrorMessageResourceName="ServiceRequest_CreatedDate")]
public System.DateTime CreatedDate {
  get { return PropertyMetadata.CreatedDate.GetValue(this); }
  set { PropertyMetadata.CreatedDate.SetValue(this, value); }
}
```

**In Code**

```
        var request = new ServiceRequest();

        // request.CreatedDate will be the date the app started not a new call to DateTime.Now or DateTime.Today
```

I verified this by manually setting my computer clock to tomorrow right before the call to new.

Is this documented and expected or is there a patch or is this a newly found bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DevForce assigns every non-nullable DataEntityProperty a DefaultValue when that property object is created and uses this default when initializing each entity object.  This means that `ServiceRequest.PropertyMetada.CreatedDate.DefaultValue` is set once when that property is created, and then used to populate the default value for CreatedDate whenever you construct a ServiceRequest instance.  To work around this behavior you can set CreatedDate to any value needed within your SerivceRequest constructor or factory creating these objects.

Comment: OK, that is what I am doing.